# I have been trying to test-sign the driver catalog file and I keep getting the signtool error: File not found. I am not sure why this error occurs?

Tags: drivers

I am trying to sign this catalog file and I have used the signtool command.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86>signtool sign /v /fd sha1 /sm Personal /i DriverMonochromator /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 prefix.cat

It seems like every command I give after the "/sm" seems to be recognized as a "FileName". This is the error I get

The following certificate was selected:
Issued to: DriverMonochromator
Issued by: DriverMonochromator
Expires:   Sat Dec 31 16:59:59 2039
SHA1 hash: E70F7745D8D42E9722A42E97A65DAC8039B940CF

Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: File not found: Personal
SignTool Error: File not found: /i
SignTool Error: File not found: DriverMonochromator
SignTool Error: File not found: /t
SignTool Error: File not found: http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1
SignTool Error: File not found: prefix.cat

Number of files successfully Signed: 0
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 6

How do I solve this?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool

Comment: /sm  Specifies that a machine store, instead of a user store, is used.... why do you put "Personal" behind that?

Comment: My certificate was under the Personal file in certlm(Certificates in Local Machine), that's why I gave so. Should I change that?

Comment: Yep, "Personal" should be removed from the command.

Comment: Okay. One more question, for the filename at the end, should I just give the filename "prefix.cat" or the entire directory of the file

Comment: It should be the filename, not the entire directory

Comment: Now, I get this                                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86>signtool sign /v /fd sha1 /sm /i DriverMonochromator /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 prefix.cat
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: DriverMonochromator
    Issued by: DriverMonochromator
    Expires:   Sat Dec 31 16:59:59 2039
    SHA1 hash: E70F7745D8D42E9722A42E97A65DAC8039B940CF

Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: File not found: prefix.cat

Number of files successfully Signed: 0
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 1

Comment: Then specify the correct location of the file (or move the file). So like `signtool sign /v /fd sha1 /sm /i DriverMonochromator /t http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 "C:\there\is\no\fork\prefix.cat"`